# How to start learning low level coding on Android

Tags: android, performance, android-traceview

I have mostly worked on C, where I need to interact with the underlying hardware and O.S. Now I am shifting to Android applications. I will be writing applications that will be time critical and involve deep understanding of Android O.S and hardware in picture.

Can some one please direct me to the resources(articles, videos) which will help me in developing successful applications:
Basically I am looking for resources on Android O.S and its interaction with the hardware.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Android is based on the linux kernel, so you can start there.. lots of books on kernel programming.

Comment: @Ran to learn android first learn linux! wat r u saying!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand the low level architecture of Android. You can find it here
http://source.android.com/devices/

Answer (score -1):

You can start from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

Very good guide for beginners